# How can I make sure a QWidget is centered horizontally in a QHBoxLayout?

Tags: qt

I have 7 QWidgets in a QHBoxLayout.
Some of these are QPushButtons and some are QLabels with custom painting (homemade gauges).
How can I make sure that the 4th widget is centered in the layout?
I want to be able to resize the layout.

Answer (score 1):

You can use horizontal `QSplitter`, and use `void QSplitter::setStretchFactor(int index, int stretch)` to set the factor of stretch.